# Paste Special Values using

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks to another user, I have been able to paste to offset range using destination, now I am trying to alter that so that it pastes as values so that my formatting and formulas don't carry along.  The paste is currently causing #REF errors because of the formulas copying over.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyPasteOffset()
    Dim OffsetRange As Long
    OffsetRange = Cells(78,1).Value
    Range("B65:F65").Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("stats FY2017").Cells(2+OffsetRange,2).PasteSpecial xlPasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Gives me an "end of statement error"

Comment: Replace `Destination:=Sheets("stats FY2017").Cells(2+OffsetRange,2).PasteSpecial xlPasteSpecial` with `Destination:=Sheets("stats FY2017").Cells(2+OffsetRange,2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
Sub CopyPasteOffset()
    Dim OffsetRange As Long
    OffsetRange = Cells(78, 1).Value
    Range("B65:F65").Copy
    Sheets("stats FY2017").Cells(2 + OffsetRange, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great.  My xlPasteSpecial was the issue, now that I look at it.  When I tried this initially that syntax is what gave me the error, its always simpler than it seems.

Comment: Glad it worked. You might have done something wrong with the syntax. :)  Please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.

Comment: Yup, was just waiting out the timer for it, had a couple minutes left on the timer before I could accept.  The syntax was specifically the xlPasteValue item that caused my syntax, I am looking back at the code now

Answer (score 0):

Here are some variations on PasteSpecial xlValues. Some include formatting but all take the values from any formulas in the original.

```
Sub CopyPasteOffset()
    Dim offsetRange As Long

    With Worksheets(1)
        offsetRange = .Cells(1, 1).Value

        'raw value transfer - slightly faster but dates become integers, time becomes doubles
        'and currency loses regional information
        With .Range("B1:F1")
            Worksheets(2).Cells(1 + offsetRange, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value2
        End With

        'value transfer - dates, times and currency are retained
        With .Range("B1:F1")
            Worksheets(2).Cells(1 + offsetRange, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
        End With

        'add a blank cell and paste the union - provides Value and Formatting transfer (strips formulas)
        '(assumes that Z1 is a blank cell that will not interfere with anything when pasted)
        .Range("B1:F1, Z1").Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets(2).Cells(1 + offsetRange, 1)

        'PasteSpecial Values, optionally paste formats
        .Range("B1:F1").Copy
            With Worksheets(2).Cells(1 + offsetRange, 1)
                .PasteSpecial xlValues
                .PasteSpecial xlFormats
            End With
    End With

End Sub
```